# Creating slides without title using md2googleslides

Tags: google-slides-api

When using the markdown to slides application `md2googleslides` the following places an image on the background of a slide with a title string

```
    ---

    # This is a title

    ![](https://source.unsplash.com/78A265wPiO4/1600x900){.background}
```

If we don't include a title string it will not be visible in presentation mode but there will still be a placeholder for one in the Google Slides Editor.

```
    ---

    ![](https://source.unsplash.com/78A265wPiO4/1600x900){.background}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to create slides that do not have this placeholder title.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried using md2gslides before (and for some reason I'm unable to install it. Always fails. *sigh*), but basing from the behavior you mentioned, it looks like it needs a title. But it's using some common Markdown rules. Have you tried adding in a *placeholder* title? Wherein you include a text, but it doesn't necessarily appear. Like for StackOverflow, if you put in `# <Placholder_title_here>` in the Answer box below, nothing will appear, but there will be a space signifying that it's there.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately the placeholder title as you suggested just throws an error. I can recommend md2gslides. I have to make sure that node js was installed for it to work.